# in the loop of large quantity query result, update operation costs strange time

Tags: python, orm, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I query a large quantity records, then loop the result. 
if I update one record, it will cost a lot time.

```
_users = db.session.query(WxUser).limit(10000).all()
for _user in _users:
    t1 = time()
    db.session.query(WxUser).filter_by(id=_user.id).update(dict(sex=WxUser.Sex.MALE))
    db.session.commit()
    t2 = time()
    print t2 - t1
```

out put:

```
0.242075920105
15.5323040485
16.6957418919
```

the commit operation cost time is more than normal.
when open the 'SQLALCHEMY_ECHO',  shows that SQLAlchemy query the every record by id.

how it happened?

Comment: Are you asking why SQLAlchemy is updating every record? Because you are querying every WxUser in your foor loop and updating its sex. In your case you are doing 10001 queries to the DB.

Comment: The query itself looks painfully slow. Why don't you try a simpler approach like `db.session.query(WxUser).limit(10000).update(dict(sex=WxUser.Sex.MALE))` and even that would take a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3270/in-the-loop-of-large-quantity-query-result

I ask SQLAlchemy author.
He gives the answer:

Two techniques will resolve the time spent.

1. turn of in-Python evaluation of objects to see if they match the criteria:

   s.query(WxUser).filter_by(id=_user.id).update(dict(data='M'),  synchronize_session=False)

docs: http: //docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html?highlight=query.update#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update.params.synchronize_session

2. don't expire all 10000 objects in the session before calling upon update(), which indicates that in order for the above synchronize_session='evaulate' to function, it must hit every single WxUser object and evaluate their "id", which requires that they be re-loaded from the database:

   session = Session(expire_on_commit=False)

docs: http: //docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#committing